# Jersey WebTarget always returns new reference

Tags: java, jersey

```
    WebTarget w0 = webTarget;
    WebTarget w1 = webTarget.queryParam("throwException", true);
    WebTarget w2 = webTarget.path(path);
    
    System.out.println(w0.getClass());

if (w0 == w1) {
    int x = 10;
    x = 20;
}

if (w1 == w2) {
    int x = 10;
    x = 20;
}
```

All these if will never be entered. WebTarget always returns new object.
This is really weird. Why is it not returning this Reference ?

Comment: is queryParam like a set Method ?

Comment: This is by design so that the WebTargets can be reused. All the methods that return a new instance, it is stated in its Javadoc.

Comment: ok . thx. So it always has to make a copy of all its attributes ?